# Write a well formatted equation in latex without taking too much space

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting

[image]

I am trying to write some equations in my papers, as you can notice, it is taking a lot of space, here is the latex code I am using. Is there a way to fix this? I would not like my code to take too much space in my paper and I would like it to be well formatted. I used `\]\[` in my code to skip a line otherwise, the equation was overflowing to the right. || means a logical OR and \And means a logical And.

```
 \[NoCallersU + NoCalleesU=None^{Callers} \And None^{Callees}\] 
 \[Low Combination=(Low^{Callers}\And(Low^{Callees} 
 || None^{Callees}))\]\[||( None^{Callers} \And Low^{Callees} )\]
 
  \[Medium Combination=(Medium^{Callers}\And(Medium^{Callees}|| \]\[ Low^{Callees}  || None^{Callees}))||(( None^{Callers} || Low^{Callers} )
  \]\[\And Medium^{Callees})\]
```

Comment: never use `\[\]` followed by another, use a multi-line display such as `gather` from the `amsmath` package. Also do not use math italic for multi-letter workds, the letters are spaced out to look like a product of variables, use `\mathit{NoCallersU }`  `\mathit{None}`  etc (or `\mathrm`)

Comment: What does `||` denote? A 'logical or'? Please advise.

Comment: yes it means logical or

Comment: use `\|` not `||`

Comment: could you please show me how to use the right operator and avcoid using line breaks and without losing too much space since I am writing a paper and I need to stay within page limits

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you nest an `aligned` environment inside a `gather*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' and 'aligned' environments
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % or: \mathrm{#1}
\newcommand\Or{\mathrel{\big\Vert}}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\vn{NoCallersU} + \vn{NoCalleesU}=\vn{None}^{\vn{Callers}} 
  \And \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}} \\[1ex]
\begin{aligned}
\vn{LowCombination}
&=\bigl(\vn{Low}^{\vn{Callers}} \And (\vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}} 
  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}})\bigr) \\
&\qquad \Or\bigl( \vn{None}^{\vn{Callers}} \And \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}} \bigr) \\[1ex]
\vn{MediumCombination}
&=\bigl(\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callers}}\And(\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}} \Or \\ 
&\qquad \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}}  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}}) \bigr) \Or \\
&\qquad \bigl(( \vn{None}^{\vn{Callers}} \Or \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callers}} ) 
 \And \vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}}\bigr)
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```