# Write equations in latex without taking too much space and without forcing line break if the equation is too long and equations to be left aligned

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, align, math-operators

I am writing the following equations in my latex paper. The problem is that these equations are taking up too much space in my paper, which is a problem since I have space limits. Also, I am forcing line breaks which is not really convenient. I would prefer if line breaks are automatically made. Also I would like all my equations to be aligned to the left.

```
    \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % or: \mathrm{#1}
\newcommand\Or{\mathrel{\big\Vert}}
% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
%\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
%\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}

% DOI
\acmDOI{xx.xxx/xxx_x}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-8104-8/21/03}

%Conference
\acmConference[SAC'21]{ACM SAC Conference}{March 22-March 26, 2021}{Gwangju, South Korea}
\acmYear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2021}

%\thispagestyle{plain} 

\acmArticle{4}
\acmPrice{15.00}


\pagestyle{plain}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true}
\begin{document}

\title{test}

\author{Anonymous Author(s)}





\begin{abstract}
abstract

\end{abstract}

%
% The code below should be generated by the tool at
% http://dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm
% Please copy and paste the code instead of the example below. 
%
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010562</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Embedded systems</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010575.10010755</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Redundancy</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010554</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Robotics</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10003033.10003083.10003095</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Networks~Network reliability</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
</ccs2012>  
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Computer systems organization~Embedded systems}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computer systems organization~Redundancy}
\ccsdesc{Computer systems organization~Robotics}
\ccsdesc[100]{Networks~Network reliability}


\keywords{ACM proceedings, \LaTeX, text tagging}


\maketitle

\begin{gather*}
\vn{NoCallersU} + \vn{NoCalleesU}=\vn{None}^{\vn{Callers}} 
  \And \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}} \\[1ex]
\begin{aligned}
\vn{LowCombination}
&=\bigl(\vn{Low}^{\vn{Callers}} \And (\vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}} 
  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}})\bigr) \\
&\qquad \Or\bigl( \vn{None}^{\vn{Callers}} \And \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}} \bigr) \\[1ex]
\vn{MediumCombination}
&=\bigl(\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callers}}\And(\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}} \Or \\ 
&\qquad \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}}  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}}) \bigr) \Or \\
&\qquad \bigl(( \vn{None}^{\vn{Callers}} \Or \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callers}} ) 
 \And \vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}}\bigr)\\[1ex]
 \vn{HighCombination}
&=\bigl(\vn{High}^{\vn{Callers}}\And(\vn{High}^{\vn{Callees}} \Or\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}} \Or \\ 
&\qquad \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}}  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}}) \bigr) \Or \\
&\qquad \bigl(\vn{High}^{\vn{Callers}}\And(\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}} \Or \\ 
&\qquad \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}}  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}}) \bigr)\\[1ex]
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}



\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of the equations when written into the paper:
[image]

Comment: Is it related to this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561909/write-a-well-formatted-equation-in-latex-without-taking-too-much-space

Comment: this a different question with a different problem

Comment: Why your code not have two columns like the screenshot? There are also 2 \usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: I didn't want to purt unrelated text that belongs to the paper and is not related to the question at hand

Comment: For your opinion how is it possibile to know to fix your code if is there not the text with the margins? You can use lipsum package.

Comment: I just fixed the code and now it is under the form of 2 columns

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the equations fit inside the narrow column is to (a) induce new line breaks immediately after `\vn{HighCombination}`, `\vn{HighCombination}` and `\vn{HighCombination}` and (b) place the alignment points for the subsequent rows further to the left.

Incidentally, I would *not* load the `lmodern` package as the `sigconf` option of the `acmart` document class specifies an alternative math and text font -- which should probably not be overridden by loading `lmodern`. And I definitely would *not* load the `fixltx2e` package unless my TeX distribution were at least five years old (which isn't the case, thankfully).

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % or: \mathrm{#1}
\newcommand\Or{\mathrel{\big\Vert}}


% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
%\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
%\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}

% DOI
\acmDOI{xx.xxx/xxx_x}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-8104-8/21/03}

%Conference
\acmConference[SAC'21]{ACM SAC Conference}{March 22--March 26, 2021}{Gwangju, South Korea}
\acmYear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2021}

%\thispagestyle{plain} 

\acmArticle{4}
\acmPrice{15.00}


\pagestyle{plain}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true}

\begin{document}
\title{test}
\author{Anonymous Author(s)}

\begin{abstract}
abstract   
\end{abstract}

%
% The code below should be generated by the tool at
% http://dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm
% Please copy and paste the code instead of the example below. 
%
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010562</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Embedded systems</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010575.10010755</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Redundancy</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010554</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Robotics</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10003033.10003083.10003095</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Networks~Network reliability</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
</ccs2012>  
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Computer systems organization~Embedded systems}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computer systems organization~Redundancy}
\ccsdesc{Computer systems organization~Robotics}
\ccsdesc[100]{Networks~Network reliability}


\keywords{ACM proceedings, \LaTeX, text tagging}


\maketitle

% \allowdisplaybreaks  % optional, to allow page breaks
\begin{gather*}
\vn{NoCallersU} + \vn{NoCalleesU}
=\vn{None}^{\vn{Callers}} 
  \And \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}} \\[1ex]
\begin{aligned}
\vn{Low}&\vn{Combination} \\
&=\bigl(\vn{Low}^{\vn{Callers}} \And (\vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}} 
  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}})\bigr) \\
&\quad \Or\bigl( \vn{None}^{\vn{Callers}} \And \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}} \bigr) \\[1ex]
\vn{Medium}&\vn{Combination}\\
&=\bigl(\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callers}}\And(\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}} \\ 
&\quad \Or \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}}  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}}) \bigr) \\
&\quad \Or \bigl(( \vn{None}^{\vn{Callers}} \Or \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callers}} ) 
 \And \vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}}\bigr)\\[1ex]
\vn{High}&\vn{Combination}\\
&=\bigl(\vn{High}^{\vn{Callers}}\And(\vn{High}^{\vn{Callees}} \Or\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}} \\ 
&\quad \Or \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}}  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}}) \bigr) \\
&\quad\Or \bigl(\vn{High}^{\vn{Callers}}\And(\vn{Medium}^{\vn{Callees}} \\ 
&\quad \Or \vn{Low}^{\vn{Callees}}  \Or \vn{None}^{\vn{Callees}}) \bigr)
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```